# Continuous image of bounded set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $B$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R $ . Prove or disprove $f(B)$ is bounded.

I think this result is true. Because since $B$ is bounded it must be contained in a closed interval $A=[-M,M]$ for some $M>0$. Then $f(A)$ is compact hence bounded. Since $B$ is contained in $A$ $f(B)$ is also contained in $f(A)$ hence $f(B)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof seems fine to me. However do note that this is not true if we allow the domain of $f$ to be restricted to non-compact sets (e.g. $f(x) = 1/x$ on the domain $\mathbb R_{> 0}$).

Comment: Sir, can you add some details of your provided example, like how given statement is false if we restrict the domain

Comment: Did you mean, for bounded subset $(0,1)$ it's image under $f$ that is $f((0, 1)) =(1, ∞)$ is not bounded